# How can I avoid Delimiters replacing Date values while printing in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

For the command:

```
cat <file_name>.asc | head -1
```

Output:

> 10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

I wanted to append commas to this line to maintain field consistency.

So I tried various combinations like issuing,
Command : echo `cat <file_name>.asc | head -1`,,,
Output : ,,,30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

Command : echo `cat <file_name>.asc | head -1`,
Output : ,0/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

Command : echo `cat <file_name>.asc | head -1`",,,"
Output : ,,,30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

Command : chk=$(echo `cat <file_name>.asc | head -1`)
echo ${chk},,,
Output : ,,,30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

But my expected output is very simple,

> 10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E,,,

Actually my logic is to open a file with CAT and do a while operation on each line to check the data and append comma wherever needed and write the output to another file.

Comment: You don't need to bother the `cat`, just `head -1 file` and: `$ echo $(head -1 file),,,`.

Comment: James, its not working dude.

Comment: Command : echo $(head -1 <file_name>.asc),,,       Output : ,,,30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E

Comment: Your file has `\r\n` (Windows style) line ending. `\r` returns cursor to the beginning of line and prints commas in the beginning. In that case use `tr` to remove the `\r`, like: `echo $(head -1 foo|tr -d '\r'),,,`

Comment: James... Thanks a lot sir... It worked... Never expected such a behaviour from Unix Script. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want do this conversion:

```
10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E --> 10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E,,,
```

If so, then you should use *sed* util:

```
cat <file_name>.asc | sed -e 's/$/,,,/' > output_file
```

Comment: Hi Ruslan, you understood me right. Command : cat <file_name>.asc | head -1 | sed -e 's/$/,,,/'    Output : ,,,30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E                         Not Working dude. I also tried removing Head command from pipe but no use.

Comment: Actually my motive is to do some thing like this, 10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E --> 10/30/2006,19:41:58,1.4871,1,E,,,<static_variable>                   So I will have to get the line file and append commas, finally end them with a static variable which I pass as argument to the script. Kindly help. It eats my head a lot.

Comment: I see that James Brown already helped you, glad to see it.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `head -n 1 cat.asc`,,,
```

If you need this in a variable, it goes like this:

```
X=`head -n 1 cat.asc`,,,
```

This answers the question which you asked. However, you also mention that you want to process a whole file and do some adjustment for each line. In this case, I don't see how this approach will help....